# how to insert data in the table which have primary and foreign key both in one table but foreign refers another table?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

My main table is Table1 and need to insert the data of table2 in table1 but getting this error

> Error report -
> ORA-02291: integrity constraint (KPI.table1_table3_FK1) violated - parent key not found:

As Table1 has primary and foreign key named as
Table1:-
Primary keys:-

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
```

And foreign key from reference of table3

```
a
b
c
d
```

Please help me with this why i'm not able to insert the data as i delete all the duplicate records as well.

I don't want to trucate or alter or drop constraints as it may effect the data count.

Please let me know for more clarity.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but does the data exist in table3 or not?

Comment: In general, if `table1` has a FK to `table3`, you need to insert the parent data in `table3` first.

Comment: table 3 exists my query is  INSERT INTO table1 
( 
    a
 b
 C
 d
 e
 f
    )

select 
     a
 b
 C
 d
 e
 f
 from table 2

Comment: and table3 structure is different i can't insert my data there

Comment: Four column is only present in table3 as per the tables 1&2

Comment: Table 1 has a foreign key dependency on Table 3. You can't insert data into Table 1 until the parent data is present in Table 3.

Comment: MTO's answer is much more detailed, but it's not a question of table3 existing, it's a question of whether a row in table3 matches the FK part of the row you want to put into table1. So table3 must have a record with the same (a,b,c,d) that you are trying to insert into table1. It doesn't matter that the structure is different since you aren't inserting the exact same data there, just the part for the FK to match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First insert data into your parent table,
Then copy the primary key of master table and send data into child table as foreign key.

Key points -
. Don't forget to commit
. Insert data in steps . First in master then in child
. If you are doing this just for learning. I will suggest you to disable the keys. First learn only DML part.  After that you can try with constraints.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is about establishing and working with  [relationship](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-foreign-key/) between tables using PK and FK. The main thing is that FK in one (detail) table reffers to the PK in another (master) table. For this to work you should first have the master table - maybe like this:

```sql
--------------------------------------------------------
--
--  DDL for Table TABLE3  -  from SQLDeveloper
--------------------------------------------------------
  CREATE TABLE "SomeUser"."TABLE3" 
   (    "ID_3" VARCHAR2(1 BYTE), 
        "SOME_T3_COL" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
   ) 
--
--  DDL for Index TABLE3_PK
  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "SomeUser"."TABLE3_PK" ON "SomeUser"."TABLE3" ("ID_3");
--
--  Constraints for Table TABLE3
  ALTER TABLE "SomeUser"."TABLE3" MODIFY ("ID_3" NOT NULL ENABLE);
  ALTER TABLE "SomeUser"."TABLE3" ADD CONSTRAINT "TABLE3_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID_3");
```

Now you have "master" table with PK defined...
Next - you need "detail" table with FK that reffers to master's PK

```sql
--------------------------------------------------------
--
--  DDL for Table TABLE1  -  from SQLDeveloper
--------------------------------------------------------
  CREATE TABLE "SomeUser"."TABLE1" 
   (    "ID_1" VARCHAR2(1 BYTE), 
        "SOME_T1_COL" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
        "FK_TO_ID_3" VARCHAR2(1 BYTE)
   );
--
--  DDL for Index TABLE1_PK
  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "SomeUser"."TABLE1_PK" ON "SomeUser"."TABLE1" ("ID_1");
--
--  Constraints for Table TABLE1
  ALTER TABLE "SomeUser"."TABLE1" MODIFY ("ID_1" NOT NULL ENABLE);
  ALTER TABLE "SomeUser"."TABLE1" ADD CONSTRAINT "TABLE1_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID_1");
--
--  Ref Constraints for Table TABLE1
  ALTER TABLE "SomeUser"."TABLE1" ADD CONSTRAINT "TABLE1_FK1" FOREIGN KEY ("ID_1")
      REFERENCES "SomeUser"."TABLE3" ("ID_3") ENABLE;
```

Now you can insert rows having in mind that master row should be inserted before you insert detail row(s) reffering to it:

```sql
Insert Into TABLE3 VALUES('a', 'some a data');    -- first insert row to the master table
Insert Into TABLE1 VALUES('a', 'some t1_a data reffering to t3PK_a --> ', 'a');   -- now you can insert detail row reffering to the master table's PK
Commit;

Insert Into TABLE3 VALUES('b', 'some b data');
Insert Into TABLE1 VALUES('b', 'some t1_b data reffering to t3PK_b --> ', 'b');
Commit;

--
--  test it:
Select t3.ID_3, t3.SOME_T3_COL, t1.SOME_T1_col, t1.FK_TO_ID_3
From TABLE3 t3
Inner Join TABLE1 t1 ON(t1.FK_TO_ID_3 = t3.ID_3);
--
--  R e s u l t:
ID_3 SOME_T3_COL          SOME_T1_COL                                        FK_TO_ID_3
---- -------------------- -------------------------------------------------- ----------
a    some a data          some t1_a data reffering to t3PK_a -->             a
b    some b data          some t1_b data reffering to t3PK_b -->             b
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the tables and sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table3 (
  a NUMBER,
  b NUMBER,
  c NUMBER,
  d NUMBER,
  PRIMARY KEY (a, b, c, d)
);

CREATE TABLE table2 (
  a NUMBER,
  b NUMBER,
  c NUMBER,
  d NUMBER,
  e NUMBER,
  f NUMBER
);

CREATE TABLE table1 (
  a,
  b,
  c,
  d,
  e NUMBER,
  f NUMBER,
  g NUMBER,
  CONSTRAINT table1__a_b_c_d_e_f_g__pk PRIMARY KEY (a, b, c, d, e, f, g),
  CONSTRAINT table1__a_b_c_d__fk FOREIGN KEY (a, b, c, d) REFERENCES table3 (a, b, c, d)
);

INSERT INTO table2 (a, b, c, d, e, f) VALUES (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO table2 (a, b, c, d, e, f) VALUES (1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2);
```

And try (based on your comment) to use:

```sql
INSERT INTO table1 (a, b, c, d, e, f)
  SELECT a, b, c, d, e, f FROM table2
```

Then you will get the error:

> ```
> ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("SCHEMA_NAME"."TABLE1"."G")
> ```

Because you have not specified a value for `g`.

If you specify a value for `g`:

```sql
INSERT INTO table1 (a, b, c, d, e, f, g)
  SELECT a, b, c, d, e, f, 42 FROM table2
```

Then you will get the error:

> ```
> ORA-02291: integrity constraint (FIDDLE_MEFJVYJLMUQDENAEVHVX.TABLE1__A_B_C_D__FK) violated - parent key not found
> ```

Because the foreign key constraint does not find matching values in the referenced table.

Then if you insert the values into `table3` so that there is a row for the referential constraint to reference:

```sql
MERGE INTO table3 dst
USING ( SELECT DISTINCT a, b, c, d FROM table2 ) src
ON (src.a = dst.a AND src.b = dst.b AND src.c = dst.c AND src.d = dst.d)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (a, b, c, d)
  VALUES (src.a, src.b, src.c, src.d);
```

Then:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (a, b, c, d, e, f, g)
  SELECT a, b, c, d, e, f, 42 FROM table2
```

Works.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/F0rHdFEX)